# Can you package an ejb interceptor in a library?

Tags: ejb-3.0, java-ee-6, interceptor

And if so how do you do it?

I have got an ejb  `@javax.interceptor.AroundInvoke` interceptor which I like to move into a library for reuse.  I moved the code into a library fixed the dependencies in maven and all compiles well now. Only on deploy I get the following error message:

```
09.02.2011 14:19:48 com.sun.logging.LogDomains$1 log
SCHWERWIEGEND: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication start method
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From *JSR 318: Enterprise JavaBeans, Version 3.1 - EJB Core Contract and Requirements*:

> **20.3 Packaging Requirements**
>
> The ejb-jar file or .war file must
>   contain, either by inclusion or **by
>   reference**, the class files of each
>   enterprise bean as follows:
>
> - The enterprise bean class.
> - The enterprise bean business interfaces, web service endpoint
>     interfaces, and home and com-ponent
>     interfaces.
> - **Interceptor classes.**
> - The primary key class if the bean is an entity bean.
>
> *We say that a .jar file contains a second file “by reference” if the
>   second file is named in the Class-Path
>   attribute in the Manifest file of the
>   referencing .jar file or is contained
>   (either by inclusion or by reference)
>   in another .jar file that is named in
>   the Class-Path attribute in the
>   Manifest file of the referencing .jar
>   file.*

So I'd say yes, you can package the interceptor class in a library .jar file.

Check that: 1) the library actually got packaged in and deployed with the ejb-jar file; and 2) the library .jar is referenced in the Manifest file as described above.

Comment: Thanks. Adding `<addClasspath>true</addClasspath>` to the `maven-ejb-plugin` did the trick. Interestingly the jar itself is not added to ejb-jar. You have to add the library to the EAR file dependencies so the lib is added to the enterprise archive. Hint for those who find this question: Don't forget `<bundleDir>lib</bundleDir>` in the pom for the `maven-ear-plugin` settings